# Rails failing when attempting to install from gem 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am attempting to install RoR on my Lubuntu box just setup today, I have installed all of the rvm requirements installed Ruby. When I go to install rails I keep getting this error.

Running the command `sudo gem install rails -V` it looks like it's trying to pull source for ruby 1.9.1 but I have 1.9.2 and then it fails out cannot load such file --mkmf (LoadError).

Any help would be much appreciated, this is my first adventure into Ruby so this is my first setup. Ask any questions and I will answer. 
 
[image]

Comment: I installed everything required from the rvm requirements to install ruby so I am assuming it's listed in there.

Comment: you shouldn't run `gem install` as `sudo`, just run `gem install rails`, or use `rvmsudo` if you installed rvm from root.

Comment: also when typing `type rvm | head -1` it should output `rvm is a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need some RVM preinstallations, open terminal and type:

```
$> sudo apt-get install curl git ruby1.8
```

Then download and install RVM itself:

```
$> curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After installing is done, load RVM:

```
$> source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

To check that RVM is installed as a function, type:

```
$> type rvm | head -1

(it should output "rvm is a function")
```

In order to work, RVM has some of it's own dependencies that need to be installed. You can see what these are using:

```
$> rvm requirements
```

For Ruby / Ruby HEAD (MRI, Rubinius, & REE), install the following:

```
$> sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
```

Once you are using RVM, installing Ruby is easy:

```
$> rvm install 1.9.3
```

In newer version of Rails, you also need a Javascript runtime, so:

```
$> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

We can continue to use RVM to install gems:

```
$> rvm rubygems current
```

Once everything is set up, it is time to install Rails:

```
$> gem install rails
```

---

P.S.

Postinstall & Troubleshooting.

When we disable GNOME Terminal's "Run command as login shell", rvm unable to load as a function, so typing:

```
$> type rvm | head -1
```

outputs something like "rvm is /home/mercurial/.rvm/bin/rvm".

In order fix this, edit ~/.bashrc and add the following line in the end of file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Comment: fan-f*ck!ng-tastic! Thank you, have been dealing with this for awhile!!! Feels good to start writing some Ruby code!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `sudo` to install your rails gem, because that'll switch to a different user which doesn't have access to your RVM installation. Just use `gem install rails`.

I would still recommend uninstalling the system Ruby.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I installed ruby from RVM not from source. I actually followed your tutorial.

Comment: You did switch to 1.9.2 (ala `rvm 1.9.2`) before attempting to install rails, right?

Comment: Updated my answer entirely. Sorry for missing the important part where you `sudo`'d. Please just use `gem install`, not `sudo gem install`. I think my guide *does* say to do that too..

Answer (score 0):

First: It doesn't seems that you are installing it using rvm at all. When using rvm it should install  or in your home or in /usr/share. This install on /usr/lib is about a normal install of ruby.

To install it on the system instead of the rvm, u should install the dev version of the ruby package, like

```
apt-get install ruby1.9-dev
```

But, if u want to isntall using rvm, as i think u wantm u should install it with

```
rvm install 1.9.3.
```

Let me know if is not your case.

Comment: this was installed using RVM

Comment: Well, maybe if u try to reinstall rvm. User 'rvm implode' to erase it, then start it all over again. This kind of errors are part of the knowledge proccess. =)